# When is a good time to reset permalinks?

Tags: permalinks

It seems "reset your permalinks" is a very common solution for your problems. In my 3 months of using Wordpress, I've never came across a situation where it actually solved my problems... UNTIL NOW!

In my functions.php:

```
<?php
// When doing this, I must re-save permalinks
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'remcat_rewrite');
function remcat_rewrite($wp_rewrite) {
    $new_rules = array('(.+)/page/(.+)/?' => 'index.php?category_name='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&paged='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(2));
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
?>
```

I'm guessing any time you rewrite rules would be a good time to reset your permalinks.

What are the standard times you would want to reset your permalinks?

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing permalinks then you need to have a plan for redirecting old urls to new or else you will create many SEO and visitor issues. If you are redirecting immediately after you make changes then time of change is not so important. If there will be a delay in the redirects being made and tested then look at your search traffic and pick a day/time where you expect to have the least visitors on your site based on past activity.